# How to pass oracle optimization hint in django query

Tags: python, django, oracle

I am using oracle 11g and have need to pass [oracle hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/hintsref.htm#PFGRF501) in django query.

Sql I need to execute in django is like this:

```
select /*+ ORDERED USE_NL(cd) */ 
* 
from table1 d 
inner join table2 cd on cd.id=d.id;
```

I don't want to perform [django raw sql query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/), but somehow to integrate in normal django ORM query - i.e. in something like this:

```
Table1.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 4):

Edit: *it seems that this kind of solution needs more testing since
[oracle reference for optimizer hints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm) says:
**Oracle ignores hints if the comment containing them does not follow a DELETE, SELECT, or UPDATE keyword.** (thanks to @swstephe to noting this out). In this solution first bracket is extra and because of this probably optimizer won't process hint at all.*

If needed you can check first which aliases django uses when creating sql:

```
qs = Table1.objects.all()
```

check query with:

```
>>> print qs.query # or qs.query.sql_with_params()
SELECT "TABLE1"."ID",... FROM "TABLE1"
```

and then you can add "extra" dummy column by using [django queryset extra method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) with column definition containing the hint:

```
>>> qs = qs.extra(select={"dummy1" : '/*+ ORDERED USE_NL("TABLE1") */ 1 '}).all()
```

If we check now the look of the query - it looks like this:

```
>>> print qs.query

SELECT (/*+ ORDERED USE_NL("TABLE1") */ 1) AS "DUMMY1", "TABLE1"."ID", 
... FROM "TABLE1"
```

Additional useful reference:

- django [database access optimization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  Oracle optimizer hints must come immediately after the "SELECT" keyword.  I checked with a query I needed to do this on, and the hint was ignored if after a value or within those parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for checking and noting this out. I would need to do more testing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  Finally found that I could only insert optimization hints using "raw", (using OP's example):

```
Table1.objects.raw("""\
    select /*+ ORDERED USE_NL(cd) */ 
    d.* 
    from table1 d 
    inner join table2 cd on cd.id=d.id
""").all()
```

But this means that you can't use the usual methods like "filter" or limit rows.  You have to do everything manually.

Here is my reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Nice, this looks fast & easy, but works only for simple cases (qs.raw() limitations).

Comment: Playing around with it a bit more, you only need to use it to select the one table you have defined.   Django can still take care of foreign key tables for you after that.